# Socket Send error as Broken Pipe

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

From A TCP client when i call the send to server. It is giving Broken Pipe error.

Answer (score 5):

A broken pipe occurs whenever you try to write data to a pipe but all of the readable ends of the pipe have closed.  In your case, it sounds like the server has closed the connection.  To see what caused the problem, call perror or strerror.

Answer (score 2):

A hint would be that the other end of the connection must be closed. Please check that part.

Comment: i don't have the any control to check on the Server side.

Comment: If you can reproduce it, check with a network monitor (tcpdump, wireshark,...)